# What is the proper way to override Stream.BeginRead given the Task-returning ReadAsync

Tags: .net, async-await, stream

I'm looking to override `BeginRead` on a custom stream. `ReadAsync` would be much easier to implement because it can use `await`. Can I reuse that code to override `BeginRead` as well? What's a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's just tedious code.

But you can find several [`TaskToApm` on source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#q=TaskToApm).

Just choose the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: This is a good solution, thanks. Can you speak to the best practice? Like, are you supposed to override at all or just ignore this?

Comment: It depends on the class. Browse [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net) and seen which one better suits your needs.